# scale to fit screen size issue Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, screen-size

I have posted about Xcode once before and must state that I am very new to this. I have been toying around with Xcode for a few days now and it is very fun but when making a basic login page I found that when I changed the screen size from iPhone 11 to say iPhone SE then it showed nothing adjusted and nothing fit the screen. I found out that I needed to put constraints on each item but when I try to add constraints it does not seem to work out well! Could anyone tell me how I adjust everything to scale to screen size in Xcode11, please!!!?

Included are the following:

- title
- view - 2x UITextFields and a login button
- you can't see it but at the bottom it "not you sign in button"

[image: when simulating on an iPhone 11]

[image: When running on an iPhone SE]

Comment: please check this out -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_0_XQEfrGQ

Comment: "but when I try to add constriants it does not seem to work out well!" What constraints have you added?